# Autohide UIScrollBar in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a dynamic text box in a Flash AS3 project.  I've attached a UIScrollBar component to it which works great if there's more text than display room.

I want to be able to hide the scrollbar when there's more display room than text.  I can't seem to find anything about it in AS3.  Does anyone know the property I should be looking for to see if the scrollbar should be displayed or not?

Thanks,
Ryan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a conditional to hide it when `tf.textHeight > tf.height`

Answer (score 1):

// after updating the text...

```
my_textfield.scrollV = 0; // reset the scroll to the top
my_scrollbar.update(); // make sure the scrollbar knows it's been changed
if (my_textfield.maxScrollV <= 1) {
    my_scrollbar.visible = false;
} else {
    my_scrollbar.visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the visible property of the UIScrollBar to false when not required. For eg :

```
scrollBar.visible = textbox.text.length < MaxLength ? false:true;
```

where

- scrollBar : The instance name of UI Component u added.
- textBox   : The instance name of textbox.
- MaxLength : The integral length beyond which scollBar should be made visible.